# Rspec redirect to testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, rspec, rspec2

In my controller when an user creates a new post, he/she is redirected to the page that contains the newly created post. I'm wanting to create a test in rspec to cover this redirect but am having trouble with it. Specifically, I want to know what to write in the refirst_to argument. Here is the controller code below..

```
def create
@micropost = Micropost.new(params[:micropost])
 respond_to do |format|
  if @micropost.save
    format.html {redirect_to @micropost}
  else
    format.html {render action: 'edit'} 
  end
end
end
```

Here is the rspec test...

```
before do
  @params = FactoryGirl.build(:micropost)
end

it "redirects to index" do
  #clearly @params.id doesn't work. its telling me instead of a redirect im getting a 
  #200
  #response.should redirect_to(@params.id)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that @params will create a valid Micropost (otherwise .save will fail and you'll be rendering :edit)...

```
it "redirects to index on successful save" do
  post :create, :micropost => @params.attributes
  response.should be_redirect
  response.should redirect_to(assigns[:micropost])
end

it "renders :edit on failed save" do
  post :create, :micropost => {}
  response.should render ... # i don't recall the exact syntax...
end
```

Comment: Hmm.. adding `micropost: @params.attributes` tells me I can't mass assign attributes. And without it, it's telling me I'm not receiving a redirect. Investigation is further required.

Comment: That error is caused by your controller call for Micropost.new(params[:micropost]). See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment

Comment: I got it to work, but I have a quick question first. What was the reason for writing `:micropost => @params.attributes` vs just `@params`?

Comment: `Micropost.new(params[:micropost])` is looking for a Hash at `params[:micropost]`  So you need to pass a hash of a hash in your test.